# std::list copy to std::vector skipping elements

Tags: c++, xcode, objective-c++, stdlist

I've run across a rather bizarre exception while running C++ code in my objective-C application.  I'm using libxml2 to read an XSD file. I then store the relevant tags as instances of the Tag class in an std::list. I then copy this list into an std::vector using an iterator on the list. However, every now and then some elements of the list aren't copied to the vector. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 printf("\n length list = %lu, length vector = %lu\n",XSDFile::tagsList.size(), XSDFile::tags.size() );
std::list<Tag>::iterator it = XSDFile::tagsList.begin();
//result: length list = 94, length vector = 0

/*
for(;it!=XSDFile::tagsList.end();++it)
{
    XSDFile::tags.push_back(*it); //BAD_ACCESS code 1  . .  very bizarre . . . . 25
}

 */
std::copy (XSDFile::tagsList.begin(), XSDFile::tagsList.end(), std::back_inserter (XSDFile::tags));

printf("\n Num tags in vector = %lu\n", XSDFile::tags.size());

if (XSDFile::tagsList.size() !=  XSDFile::tags.size())
{
    printf("\n length list = %lu, length vector = %lu\n",XSDFile::tagsList.size(), XSDFile::tags.size() );
    //result: length list = 94, length vector = 83
}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: I think that XSDFile class implements it's own iterator so it can skip iterating some elements on a purpose.

Comment: Why not just:  `std::copy (XSDFile::tagsList.begin(), XSDFile::tagsList.end(), std::back_inserter (XSDFile::tags));`?

Comment: @JohnDibling Yes that's better, however the OP's code should work too.

Comment: @trojanfoe:  That's why I only commented, rather than answered.

Comment: Are you sure `XSDFile::tags` is empty before this code is run?

Comment: In truth the exception occurs later in my code as a result of the missing tags in the array. The above code runs fine. And the XSDFile::tags is only instantiated here, so it should be empty. XSDFile is a class I've created to parse the XSD using libxml2.

Comment: I just tried std::copy and the result is the same. The first 4 times I ran the code it worked but on the fifth, the number of tags in the vector was 83 while the size of the list is 94.

Comment: Can you modify your error print to actually print the values of size at that point?  Do they match when you have an error later?

Comment: More importantly print the values before and after the code is run.

Comment: Before: Length list = 94 length vector = 0

Comment: After: Length list = 94 length vector 83. These lengths are the same when I have errors later in the code. Most of the time I do get the proper result though and the length of the vector matches that of the list.

Comment: @Jays:  If it's inconsistent, then I suspect its an error outside of the code you're showing.  I would recommend a tool such as `valgrind`

Comment: Valgrind . . never heard of it. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: As a final guess, does the `Tag` destructor/constructor do anything with either of these two containers?  I ask, because it appears that these containers are static members, so it would be possible.

Comment: Tag is just a basic class which has nothing but setters and getters. It doesn't do anything to either containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. The memory was corrupted causing the std::list to become corrupted during the parsing of the XSD. I parse the XSD using a function start_element.

```
xmlSAXHandler handler = {0};
handler.startElement = start_element;
```

I used malloc guard in xcode to locate the use of freed memory. It pointed to the line:

```
std::strcpy(message, (char*)name);
```

So I removed the *malloc* (actually commented in the code) and it worked. The std::vector now consistently copies all 94 entries of the list. If anyone has an explanation as to why this worked that would be great.

```
static void start_element(void * ctx, const xmlChar *name, const xmlChar **atts)
{    
// int len = strlen((char*)name);

//    char *message = (char*)malloc(len*sizeof(char));
//    std::strcpy(message, (char*)name);

if (atts != NULL)
{
 //   atts[0] = type
 //   atts[1] = value

 //   len = strlen((char*)atts[1]);
 //   char *firstAttr = (char*)malloc(len*sizeof(char));
 //   std::strcpy(firstAttr, (char*)atts[1]);


     if(strcmp((char*)name, "xs:include")==0)
     {   
         XSDFile xsd;
         xsd.ReadXSDTypes((char*)atts[1]);
     }

     else if(strcmp((char*)name, "xs:element")==0)
     {
         doElement(atts);
     }


     else if(strcmp((char*)name, "xs:sequence")==0)
     {
         //set the default values
         XSDFile::sequenceMin = XSDFile::sequenceMax = 1;

         if (sizeof(atts) == 4)
         {
            if(strcmp((char*)atts[3],"unbounded")==0)
                XSDFile::sequenceMax = -1;

             int i = 0;
             while(atts[i] != NULL)
             {
                 //atts[i] = name
                 //atts[i+i] = value

                 std::string name((char*)atts[i]);
                 std::string value((char*)atts[i+1]);

                 if(name=="minOccurs")
                     XSDFile::sequenceMin = (atoi(value.c_str()));
                 else if(name=="maxOccurs")
                     XSDFile::sequenceMax = (atoi(value.c_str()));

                 i += 2;
             }

         }

     }
}

//free(message);
}
```